# Delete entire row, if a cell has a background color

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete all the rows of which the cell in column D has a background color. I have written the code below, but everytime I run it, it runs indefinitely until it eventually crashes. Both `ws1` and `lastrow2` are well defined (I mention it to clear this possibility of why my macro is not running)

```
With ws1
    lastrow2 = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastrow2 To 2 Step -1
        nodel = False

        If .Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 0 Then
            nodel = True
        End If

        If Not nodel Then
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: try `If .Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use ***0***:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
    Dim Nodel As Boolean
    With ws1
        lastrow2 = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lastrow2 To 2 Step -1
            Nodel = False
            If .Cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then
               Nodel = True
            End If
            If Not Nodel Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

If you want to retain cells with a white background, first verify that "white" corresponds to "colorindex=2" and then use ***2*** in place of ***-4142*** in the code.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not run.. I just figured out that the background color of the cells I want to keep is not no fill but it is white.. does this change anything?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas  Yes, it will change things!

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas  on my system *white* is ***2*** rather than ***-4142***

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas  see my **Edit#1**